# Slide a slideshow upon clicking a botton in it

Tags: views, javascript

I have a jcarousel displaying full contents including some fields. Two flags are also included. If any flag is clicked, say A or B, I want d jcarousel to show the next content and so on, so that d user will not need to click on 'next' himself.
Moreso, the contents may be very long. I want d next slide to show from rhe top and not needing one to scroll up again.
Thanks

Comment: No comment still?

Comment: ?????¿??????? Please